# Method of moments to estimate a parameter

Tags: self-study, inference, unbiased-estimator, estimators, method-of-moments

> Suppose that $Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n$ is a random sample from a
>   distribution with density function
>
> $$ f(y) =  \begin{cases} \theta y^{\theta - 1}\ \ \ \ 0 < y < 1, \\ 0\
>  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  elsewhere \end{cases} $$
>
> The parameter $\theta$ is positive.
>
> Use the method of moments to estimate the parameter $\theta$.

Comment: should this have the self-study tag? read this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Answer (score 1):

Hint: it follows directly from the definition of method of moments. You only have to solve one equation for $\theta$.